# Expose api in monolithyc Jhipster APP with OAUTH2 base Security

Tags: jhipster

Can anybody help me?

I built a Jhipster monolithyc app using Security based on Keycloak. This keycloak access to my corporative ldap and all works perfect. When somebody wants a page it redirects to http://localhost:8080/login and it redirect to keycloak to sing in, it returns to http://localhost:8080/login and it gets the token of the login user, so the user can access base on his role-user permissions.

Now, we want to expose the api to third party companies so as to reuse the bussiness logic of my app. (we can do it with web services but we want to expose our restful api). They have their own applications (desktop, web, etc) and we want to expose our api so they can communicate with us with the same securicy policies. they have users in our ldap. can anybody tell me which is the best way to expose it with user-role permissions.

One way is that they can send us their login information (user, password). We know it is not the best way , but we dont know how to do it other way. Does anybody know how to login with keycloak based on this user login. We enabled direct conecction and we are able to get the Keycloak access token with password flow. But, if we do this way, how can we convert this token in a OAuth2Authentication object so we can generate JSESSIONID to make the calls to the api?

We disabled csrf to make this possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days research, I reached a solution.

Here is the code:

@Configuration

@EnableResourceServer

public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean("resourceServerRequestMatcher")
public RequestMatcher resources() {
    return new AntPathRequestMatcher("/external-access/**");
}

@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatcher(resources()).authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

}

This way I have both WebSecurity based on Keycloak and password flow base Resource. For this solution, the api I want to expose has both /api /external-api mappings, first for web navigation and the other for direct access. To access via the second way you have to call first keycloak to get a token and then access /external-api with that token.

Perhaps there is a better solution (client credentials), but i need the login user to resuse my endpoints.